# How to add a key value pair to an array in Javascript / Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have 2 arrays as below

```
var dataSource = [
{location: "France", January: 79, February: 81, March: 23},  
{location: "Germany", January: 98, February: 83},
{location: "Japan", January: 96, March: 11} ];

var Months = ["January","February","March"];
```

I want to loop through each object in `dataSource` and check if all values of `Months` exist in each objects of `dataSource`. If the value doesn't exist in `dataSource` then add that value to `dataSource` with value = 100

example : in location Germany, the month "March" does not exist so I need to push the key and value `March : 100`

at the end `dataSource` should be as below

```
var dataSource = [
{location: "France", January: 79, February: 81, March: 23},  
{location: "Germany", January: 98, February: 83, March: 100},
{location: "Japan", January: 96, February: 100, March: 11} ];
```

I tried many solutions from previous threads but I am not getting the exact result I want. Here are some of my ideas

```js
var dataSource = [
{location: "France", January: 79, February: 81, March: 23},  
{location: "Germany", January: 98, February: 83},
{location: "Japan", January: 96, March: 11} ];

var Months = ["January","February","March"];

dataSource.forEach(function(element) {
Months.forEach(function(item) {
  if (!(item in element)) {
//Object.assign(dataSource, {item: 100}); 
//dataSource = {...dataSource, ...{item: 100}}
dataSource.push({item: 100});
  }
});
});

console.log(dataSource);
```

Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to iterate the `dataSource` array. Use an internal [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to iterate the Months, and add missing months to the current object:

```js
const dataSource = [{"location":"France","January":79,"February":81,"March":23},{"location":"Germany","January":98,"February":83},{"location":"Japan","January":96,"March":11}];
const Months = ["January","February","March"];

const result = dataSource.map(o =>
  Months.reduce((obj, m) => m in obj ? obj : { ...obj, [m]: 100 }, o)
);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can loop through the sources and months, setting the months on the sources as the value they already have, or defaulting to 100.

```js
var dataSource = [{
    location: "France",
    January: 79,
    February: 81,
    March: 23
  },
  {
    location: "Germany",
    January: 98,
    February: 83
  },
  {
    location: "Japan",
    January: 96,
    March: 11
  }
];

var Months = ["January", "February", "March"];

dataSource.forEach(function(element){
  Months.forEach(function(month){
    if (element[month] === undefined) element[month] = 100;
  });
});

console.log(dataSource);
```

Comment: This will change an explicit `0` to `100`.

Comment: @Barmar nice catch, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Or else, you can create a hash with resultant months and their values, which you can be directly used, by assigning each object of your array on top of it. So you can process `N` number of inputs (arrays) with the same hash.

Example of Resultant Hash: `{January: 100, February: 100, March: 100}`

And then you can do this `N` number of time:

```
dataSource1.map(d => ({...hash, ...d}));
dataSource2.map(d => ({...hash, ...d}));
dataSource3.map(d => ({...hash, ...d}));
```

Here is the example:

```js
let dataSource = [{"location":"France","January":79,"February":81,"March":23},{"location":"Germany","January":98,"February":83},{"location":"Japan","January":96,"March":11}],
    Months = ["January","February","March"],
    hash = Months.reduce((r, e) => ({...r, [e]: 100}), {}),
    res = dataSource.map(d => ({...hash, ...d}));
    
console.log('This is your hash: ', hash); //This is the hash generated one time
console.log('This is your result: ', res); //this is the result against that input
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you some. Just run `test()` in the developer tools or something and look at the console.log output

pay attention to the `uniqueKeys` object since its where the main logic is centered around and the hasOwnProperty stuff

```
function test() {

    var uniqueKeys = {location: ''};                        //default to have location set
    var Months = ['January', 'February', 'March'];

    for (var i = 0; i < Months.length; i++) {
        uniqueKeys[Months[i]] = '';                     //just populate the object from the array to use soon
    }


    for (var i = 0; i < dataSource.length; i++) {




        var validObject = true;
        Object.keys(uniqueKeys).forEach((e,j) => {

            if (dataSource[i].hasOwnProperty(e) === false) {
                validObject = false;
            }

        });

        if (validObject === false) {

            console.log('add to', dataSource[i], 'to balance it out');

        }
    }
}
```

hope it helps some
~cheers

Answer (score 0):

May be this short solution that iterates over the months and checks whether that month is present in each record for datasource. If not then add default value, 100 in your case

```
for(i=0;i<dataSource.length;i++){
        for(j=0;j<Months.length;j++){
            if(Months[j] in dataSource[i]){
            }
            else{
                dataSource[i][Months[j]] = 100;
            }   
        }
    }
```